# What is the psuedo-code for Tremaux's Algorithm as a Depth First Search to solve a maze?

Tags: graphs, data-structures

I was interested in the Tremaux Algorithm as a Depth First Search to solve a Maze.
Unfortunately I was not able to understand what **Data Structures** are and how they could be used.

For example, I saw a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OzpKm4te-E) which shows the process of solving a Maze using the Tremaux Algorithm but I did not understand what data structures are and how they could be implemented to mark the shortest path to reach the final destination.

Thank you for your time and help in advance.

Comment: In trémaux's algorithm, each time you reach a **new** square, you add all the adjacent squares (i.e. the ones you can move to) which you haven't visited before (i.e. don't add the one from where you came) to a (e.g.) **stack**. You then iterate over the stack (pop squares) and recursively apply Trémaux's algorithm on each square from the stack.

Comment: By square you mean a new junction? And what about if we reach a previously visited junction?

Comment: Plus according that video, you can actually find the shortest path. How is that possible? Thank you for your cooperation sir.